# How long passed between S5 E10 and S6 E9?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the last episode of season 5 we see

> Drogon appear at the fighting pit to save Daenerys

And then in season 6 episode 9 we see

> Daenerys ride Drogon and burn the master's ships

It seemed to me that

> Drogon had grown a LOT in that time

So how long passed between these episodes?

Comment: See http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/55887

Answer (score 4):

### Drogon's robustness and growth

Drogon was always more robust than his siblings. He always grew at a really fast rate.

From [Show-wiki](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Drogon):

> **Drogon is slightly larger than his siblings.** Over the course of the series he has grown considerably, from being roughly the size of a
>   kitten in Season 1 to the size of a small whale in Season 5.

This may have to do with the fact that Drogon always flew freely while Rhaegel and Viserion were chained under the pyramid. It is a known fact that Dragons best thrive in freedom. Targaryens had built a dragonpit to chain their dragons in Kingslanding which resulted in gradual decrease in size of dragons and their eventual demise.

From Books Barristan Selmy told Dany this:

> A dragon never stops growing, your Grace, so long as he has food and
>   freedom.

Later he explained his point about dragons in captivity:

> It was noted that none of the dragons ever reached the
>   size of their ancestors. The maesters say it was because of the walls
>   around them, and the great dome above their heads.

If you see the scene where Rhaegel and Viserion break out of the pyramid and fly with drogon in formation, you will notice they are much smaller than Drogon despite being of the same age.

You can see it in the battle video at 1:29:

---

### Speculation at Chronology

I do not believe we have any way of determining chronology by TV show because we do not know in Show canon how Long does it take to travel from Meereen to Vaes Dothrak, we do not know where was Dany picked up by the Dothraki and of course TV show can increase traveling speed when they want to e.g. Littlefinger's trip to the North. And of course, many of the events happen concurrently.

The [show wikia](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline) puts the events of Season 5 in year 302 AL and events of season 6 in 303 AL. Since we are calculating time from last episode of Season 5, it must be less than a year as season 6 hasn't ended yet either. So at max, we can say nine months have passed probably.

If I were to venture a guess I'd say that It must have been **4-9 months** at least because in this time:

1. Daenerys travelled to Vaes Dothrak and back
2. The Masters assembled their fleets and launched an attack after
   feigned negotiations while envoys travelled to and from Meereen.
3. Jon Snow assembled his men and travelled to many places in North to gain support against Ramsay,
4. Jaime got back from Dorne. Then he went to Riverlands.
5. And ofcourse, Petyr Baelish's lightening fast travels are there as well.
6. Also as suggested by an anonymous user, Theon was in North  in EP 2
   and in EP 9 he was in Meereen which lies halfway across the
   Planetos.

Anyways, Drogon's bigger size is due to his own robustness and freedom, not because it has been a really long time.

Comment: You should not count events from other characters to build a timeline, it has been said a few times that just because things are shown in 1 episode, does not mean they are occurring at the same time or even chronologically. Not that i disagree with anything in your answer, just a tip for the future.

Comment: @Vahx I have noted in the answer that there is no way to precisely judge the chronology because many of the events are occurring simultaneously. But we have to build on what we have, seeing the nature of the question

Comment: Yet you simply cannot use other character's POV scenes to build a timeline (unless the cross over of course).  GRRM is pretty clear on this, you may as well just remove those points as they're irrelevant.

Comment: @EdS. That's your opinion and you are entitled to it. I however believe they are relevant because that's the only thing to build on here. There is literally nothing else. There is no indication that these events are happening in serial or parallel, it's just out there that they happened. If you disagree and have a better perspective, do post it as answer, I would def upvote it if it is good enough

Comment: It's not 'my opinion'; it is what GRRM has specifically stated.  See "A Note on chronology" in the opening of ACoK (http://i.imgur.com/OcrkgkO.png).  The fact that there is nothing else to go off of is, again irrelevant.  Missing information doesn't mean that you can just make stuff up and be correct.  I don't have the answer, I'm only saying that using POV's which do not cross over as a way to build a timeline makes no sense.

Comment: I meant "remove all those points" is your opinion. I know GRRM's pov on this and we do know how things overlap and.happen concurrently in last two books. I am not making anything up. Can you point to one thing that I have made up here? These travels happened, without me making any of them up or.claiming any sequence between. Nor did I make up the time. I specifically said it's a guess. The year thing is derived from show canon which I hope you know is now deviated from books. It's only guess work. Idk if I am not clarifying correctly or what